# Why does part of mesh fly away when exported?

Tags: mesh, export, .fbx

I have the following model:

[image]

When I export it, a part of the mesh flies away:

[image]

Does anybody see what causes this?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you didn't apply rotation and scale.

So select that object (just the part which flies away) and press <kbd>CTRL-A</kbd> and then "rotation & scale".

Then export and import again -> works ...und Oma kann auch wieder besser sitzen ;)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: you are welcome